# IMAP и чтение писем хороших и разных с помощью PHP imap_fetchbody

Tags: php, кодировка, email, imap

Вот уж не думал, что что-то может добавить головняка больше чем регулярные выражения. Но нет, это может сделать попытка написать собственный php клиент для получения писем с ящика.

Суть проблемы: получаем письма с помощью imap_fetchbody, далее нам надо определить encoding.
получаем мы такую простыню

```
    stdClass Object
(
[type] => 1
[encoding] => 0
[ifsubtype] => 1
[subtype] => MIXED
[ifdescription] => 0
[ifid] => 0
[ifdisposition] => 0
[ifdparameters] => 0
[ifparameters] => 1
[parameters] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [attribute] => boundary
                [value] => =-dsffdsfdsdsfsdf
            )

    )

[parts] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [type] => 1
                [encoding] => 0
                [ifsubtype] => 1
                [subtype] => ALTERNATIVE
                [ifdescription] => 0
                [ifid] => 0
                [ifdisposition] => 0
                [ifdparameters] => 0
                [ifparameters] => 1
                [parameters] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [attribute] => boundary
                                [value] => =-ffdsfdsfdsfds
                            )

                    )

                [parts] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [type] => 0
                                [encoding] => 2
                                [ifsubtype] => 1
                                [subtype] => PLAIN
                                [ifdescription] => 0
                                [ifid] => 0
                                [lines] => 1
                                [bytes] => 74
                                [ifdisposition] => 0
                                [ifdparameters] => 0
                                [ifparameters] => 1
                                [parameters] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [attribute] => charset
                                                [value] => UTF-8
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [type] => 0
                                [encoding] => 3
                                [ifsubtype] => 1
                                [subtype] => HTML
                                [ifdescription] => 0
                                [ifid] => 0
                                [lines] => 3
                                [bytes] => 218
                                [ifdisposition] => 0
                                [ifdparameters] => 0
                                [ifparameters] => 1
                                [parameters] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [attribute] => charset
                                                [value] => UTF-8
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [type] => 3
                [encoding] => 3
                [ifsubtype] => 1
                [subtype] => OCTET-STREAM
                [ifdescription] => 0
                [ifid] => 1
                [id] => 
                [bytes] => 6850824
                [ifdisposition] => 1
                [disposition] => attachment
                [ifdparameters] => 0
                [ifparameters] => 1
                [parameters] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [attribute] => name
                                [value] => =?UTF-8?B?0L/fdsfdsfdsfdsf=?=
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

мы знаем, что для корректной обработки тела письма нам необходимо получить **encoding**
Но, если для некоторых писем сработает `$encoding=@$dsasdfs[1]->encoding;`, то для других нужно будет `$encoding=@$dsasdfs[0]->encoding;` или например `$encoding=@$dsasdfs[4]->encoding;`
так как количество объектов всегда разное, и это зависит, судя по всему, от количества частей, из которых состоит письмо (вложения, их количество, тип текста письма, тип вложения и тп), то какие-либо попытки предсказать, по какому encoding нам ориентироваться для того, чтобы юзать

```
imap_utf8
imap_8bit
imap_binary
base64_decode
```

и некоторые другие функции, ломают вообще желание что-то делать.
Реальный гуглёж на протяжении 5 часов ничего не дал по моей проблеме.

если кто-то реально делал такую же фигню и решил эту проблему - буду признателен за помощь.

Comment: А зачем вы пытаетесь применить некую кодировку ко всему письму в целом. У каждой части из которой состоит письмо может быть собственная кодировка, отличная от других. Рассматривайте каждую часть в отдельности

Comment: я не применяю ко всему письму. моя задача получить текст письма, это как минимум, в идеале, конечно, разобрать все части и склеить в полноценное письмо, но на данном этапе мне нужно понять как получить читабельный текст.

Comment: получаю текст письма я 
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to mail: ' . imap_last_error());
$message = (imap_fetchbody($inbox,$id,1.1)); 
где $id - номер письма

Answer (score 0, accepted):

видимо, слишком сложный вопрос :)
я все-таки нашел ответ
спасибо @Makram
приведу код здесь:

```
function getBody($uid, $imap) {
$body = $this->get_part($imap, $uid, "TEXT/HTML");
// if HTML body is empty, try getting text body
if ($body == "") {
    $body = $this->get_part($imap, $uid, "TEXT/PLAIN");
}
return $body;
}

function get_part($imap, $uid, $mimetype, $structure = false, $partNumber = false) {
    if (!$structure) {
       $structure = imap_fetchstructure($imap, $uid, FT_UID);
    }
    if ($structure) {
        if ($mimetype == $this->get_mime_type($structure)) {
            if (!$partNumber) {
                $partNumber = 1;
            }
            $text = imap_fetchbody($imap, $uid, $partNumber, FT_UID);
            switch ($structure->encoding) {
                case 3: return imap_base64($text);
                case 4: return imap_qprint($text);
                default: return $text;
            }
        }
    // multipart
    if ($structure->type == 1) {
        foreach ($structure->parts as $index => $subStruct) {
            $prefix = "";
            if ($partNumber) {
                $prefix = $partNumber . ".";
            }
            $data = $this->get_part($imap, $uid, $mimetype, $subStruct,
                $prefix. ($index + 1));
            if ($data) {
                return $data;
            }
        }
    }
}


  return false;
}

function get_mime_type($structure) {
    $primaryMimetype = array("TEXT", "MULTIPART", "MESSAGE", "APPLICATION",
        "AUDIO", "IMAGE", "VIDEO", "OTHER");

    if ($structure->subtype) {
       return $primaryMimetype[(int)$structure->type] . "/" . $structure->subtype;
    }
    return "TEXT/PLAIN";
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25503969/locate-html-and-plain-text-using-imap-fetchstructure